# Best way to use quickbooks-php for direct queries

Tags: quickbooks-online

I have a client that has all the queries already built. He would like to:

1. Authenticate using the PHP library
2. Directly send a query (SELECT * FROM Vendor)
3. Output the result

What is the best way to do so?

The query is currently sent through the corresponding entity in the provided exemples.

`$VendorService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Vendor();`

`$vendors = $VendorService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Vendor");`

Is there a neutral object that the `Service` class can extend from that only serves as a carrier of a query result?

Exemple: `$result = $DirectQuery->query($Context, $realm, "ANY SELECT QUERY HERE")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use any of the classes to run any where you want. e.g. this will work just fine:

```
$VendorService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Vendor();

$customers = $VendorService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Customer");
$invoices = $VendorService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Invoice");
$payments = $VendorService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Payment");
```

If you want the raw XML you get back from Intuit, you can get it by calling this method after `->query(...)`:

```
$raw_xml_response = $VendorService->lastResponse();
```

Comment: It's a software that contacts my PHP gateway. I have no clue what he will request in advance, that's why I wanted to skip the models and return the raw JSON but STILL use the PHP API Auth.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking here... are you saying you don't want to use classes at all? You're just trying to get the raw JSON or XML back from Intuit?

Comment: Yes! But I would like the Authorization process to be managed by the PHP library.

Comment: $xml = $VendorService->lastResponse(); will get you the raw response from Intuit.

Comment: This solution works! Even though I ask for other things than clients, it still provides me with the API response. There's prolly a way to make it JSON as well.